# Remote debugging Java web app running in Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I have a web application. It is currently deployed on a remote server in a Glassfish instance. Is it possible to remotely connect to the server and debug the application (like I would a normal java application) using Netbeans?

If someone has done this and could provide insight or could point me to a guide, that would be great.

I know this functionality exists with Visual Studio and ASP.Net. I was not sure if there is a java equivalent.

Most examples that I have seen online are for applications that are simply running on a remote machine or for debugging a Glassfish application running on the local machine.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Once you have GlassFish running in debug mode, go to the **Debug** menu in NetBeans and click on **Attach Debugger...**, which brings up the *Attach* dialog. You'll probably go with something like:

> Debugger: Java Debugger (JPDA)
>
> Connector: SocketAttach
>
> Transport: dt_socket
>
> Host: hostname_or_ip_address
>
> Port: 9009

*Timeout* may be left blank. When you click *OK* on this dialog, you should be able to connect your NetBeans debugger to GlassFish.

Remember:

1. The firewall on your remote server (and any gateways in between) should allow connections to the debugger port (9009 in my example).
2. Make sure you're using matching port numbers. In the GlassFish admin console, usually at: http://localhost:4848
3. Expand **Configurations**.
4. Expand **server-config** (or whichever you are using).
5. Click **JVM Settings**.
6. Check **Debug** to **Enabled**.
7. Verify that **Debug Options** contains:

   ```
   -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009
   ```

Read the [JPDA docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html) for other options you can use.

Comment: If using Netbeans, you can find the port on the debugger console, e.g: "Attaching to localhost:9009 "