# Speed Up Web App Development Testing and Debugging on Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, spring, maven, netbeans, glassfish

I use the following frameworks for my web application:

- Maven
- Spring MVC 3.2.4
- Spring Security 3.1.4

I use Netbeans 7.3 and Glassfish 3.1.2 and it is a maven project.

And it's been painfully slow that I need to restart the Glassfish re-build and re-run the project just to be able to test the code that I change every single minute. Changes to jsp files can be updated by the auto-deploy just fine, but somehow to be able to test the changes to the mvc controller I need to re-build and re-run the project (by turning off the glassfish and right click on the project and select `clean and build` and select then `run`). And each run takes about 10-15 minutes. Is there any less painful way to test my code?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the purpose, scope, and funding of your project, you might consider [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). It's not cheap, but it's affordable for a business project and free for work on open-source software. They've basically built an insanely flexible version of the JVM hot-swap setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **use a debugger**.

Start Glassfish in debug more - [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/arungupta/archive/2007/06/debug_applicati.html) explains how to do that. If not starting Glassfish from NeatBeans [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10486304/2071828) gives you the settings to allow remote debugging in NetBeans.

Now you are "attached" to the Glassfish JVM via the NetBeans debugger. You can insert breakpoints into the code and the application will stop at them. You can inspect variable values.

You can make changes to code and use the "Apply Code Changes" option under the "Deubug" menu to send the changed classes to the JVM.

This should reduce the amount of time required to test code changes to a few seconds.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joWldbcp1So) is a short YouTube tutorial on the NetBeans debugger.

Comment: What about right clicking on the project and selecting `debug` is that it?

Comment: You can try it. I haven't had much success with that and webapps - depends on how Glassfish is configured in NetBeans.

Comment: To be honest I prefer to run the WebServer outside of NetBeans and attach remotely...

Comment: why is that? Even though they both run on the same computer?

Comment: They run on different JVMs so it's called "remote".