# How to debug a javaweb application in Netbean

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

How can you do logs, watch variable, threads
I have tried the debug mode but it doesn't stop at the breakpoints.

[image]

Edit: I tried to "Attach Debugger" like below but it just said "handshake failed" or "connection refused

[image]

result:

[image]

I'm building a java web application with netbean 8.2 using GlassFish server and kind of new to this technology, so please be gentle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10486304/5788396) on how to setup Glassfish for debugging in NetBeans.

And for logs you have to switch to the "Output"-Panel in NetBeans, the threads you can see in your Screenshot on the left in the "Debug"-Panel and for watches do a right click on your "Variables"-Panel (in the bottom on your screenshot), or click in the toolbar on "Window" -> "Debug" -> "Watches".

Hope that helps.

Regards

BTW: You tagged your question with java-web-start, but it has nothing to do with Java-Web-Start / JNLP as far as I can see, maybe you should change the tag to glassfish, jee or smth like that.